# Proving that a NFA where all states must be on an accepting state is equivalent to a DFA

Tags: computer-science, automata

Here is the full question:

Recall that NFA accepts a string as long as at least one of the states that the machine is an accepting state, after consuming the entire input.  Here, we define strict-NFA that computes similarly as a normal NFA but this machine accepts input string w if all states that the machine is in are strictly from the set of accept states.  Show that strict-NFA is equivalent to DFA.

I am really not sure how to get started on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the standard NFA-to-DFA construction should still be applicable, except that one has changed the rules for marking final states.  Of course, changing that rule does change the language accepted vis-a-vis the standard NFA, but I think the NFA-to-DFA construction respects that.